# How to ignore discord.py [getaddress failed] error

Tags: python, discord.py

My Wi-Fi is sometimes unstable, so I want to ignore the [getaddress failed] errors when there is no Internet. Is there any way to put a try-except block around that?

Here's the full error in case you don't know it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 964, in _create_direct_connection
    hosts = await asyncio.shield(self._resolve_host(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 829, in _resolve_host
    addrs = await \
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\resolver.py", line 29, in resolve
    infos = await self._loop.getaddrinfo(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 825, in getaddrinfo
    return await self.run_in_executor(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 548, in connect
    self.ws = await asyncio.wait_for(coro, timeout=60.0)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 483, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 296, in from_client
    gateway = gateway or await client.http.get_gateway()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 910, in get_gateway
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/gateway'))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 185, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 480, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 858, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 971, in _create_direct_connection
    raise ClientConnectorError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:default [getaddrinfo failed]
```

I am aware of the fact that there is an event in discord.py called on_disconnect(), but it still allows the error to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed with commit [a9824ff](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/commit/a9824ffabf0b2c8031ac75245650711145aaa26c) on Aug 5. Please update discord.py to *at least* v1.4.0 which contains that fix.

Comment: My discord.py version is 1.5.0, and I'm wondering if you can put a try-except block instead of displaying the error, it can say "Oops! You don't have internet, so the bot won't work!"

Comment: Ah, I see. There is an [on_error event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_error) you can use, where you can ignore it. If the bot terminates by this, then I am not sure what you can do about it. Other than putting a `while True` statement around `run()`.
An unstable connection is not the best environment for hosting a discord bot.